# Python Requests library handshake error

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests, handshake

I'm facing a specially devilish error when trying to make a simple post request to a https website, using requests module. It raises:

```
"requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)"
```

I've tried uninstalling and installing modules, installing extra dependencies (as recommended by related threads), mounting adapters with different protocols... I just don't know any way around it. 
Would greatly appreciate any help. 
It looks something like this:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'}

def t(DNI):
    DNI = str(DNI)
    rq = requests.Session()
    g = rq.post(HTTPS_URL, data = data, headers = headers)
    return g

a = t(10000000)
print(a)
```

Comment: Please, consider adding the code you have written (minimal test case).

Comment: I avoided adding sensitive information. Any https would do